# Does This Ring have a Name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory

Let $M_1=\{0,1,2,4,5,8,9,10,\cdots\}$ be the set of nonnegative integers that can be written as a sum of two perfect squares. Let $M_2=\{\sqrt{m}: m\in M_1\}=\{0,1,\sqrt{2},2,\sqrt{5},\cdots\}$. Let $R$ be the set of all real numbers that can be expressed as a finite linear combination of elements of $M_2$ with integer coefficients. So, for example, $3+2\sqrt{5}-6\sqrt{10}\in R$. Then $R$ forms a ring with the usual addition and multiplication defined on the reals. Does $R$ have a specific name? Does it appear anywhere in the literature or is there anything at all that I can read about it? Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to know? Its elements are algebraic integers and there are many algebraic number theory textbooks you can read to learn about algebraic integers in general.

Comment: If the main point is that it's cool that the product of a sum of two perfect squares is again a sum of two perfect squares, one algebraic context in which to view that result is the Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (a much smaller and more manageable ring!). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer#Norm_of_a_Gaussian_integer for details.

Comment: I would really just like to know if this ring is Euclidean. I thought I'd ask this question before trying to prove that it is.

Comment: It shouldn't be a Euclidean ring because it shouldn't be a UFD.